# Mongoose Error stating that it cannot populate a path because its not in my schema - but im not populating anything?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two routes in my server. Both routes are identical minus one using $push and one using $pull. The $pull route works as it should but always responds with an error of

> "MongooseError: Cannot populate path `scenes` because it is not in
> your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override."

while the $push route works perfect and responds accordingly. I am very confused as to why I am getting a populate error considering I am not populating? I do have a 'scenes' property but not in either Model being used in these routes.

```
router.put('/scene/:sceneId/addactor/:actorId', async (req, res) => {
const actorId = req.params.actorId;
const sceneId = req.params.sceneId;
try {
    const actor = await Actor.findById(actorId);
    await Scene.findByIdAndUpdate(sceneId, { $push: { actors: actor } }, { new: true }).then(dbSceneData => {
        res.status(200).send(dbSceneData);
    })
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(`An Error Ocurred: ${error}`);
}
```

});

```
router.put('/scene/:sceneId/removeactor/:actorId', async (req, res) => {
const actorId = req.params.actorId;
const sceneId = req.params.sceneId;
try {
    const actor = await Actor.findById(actorId);
    await Scene.findByIdAndUpdate(sceneId, { $pull: { actors: actor } }, { new: true }).then(dbSceneData => {
        res.status(200).send(dbSceneData);
    })
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(`An Error Ocurred: ${error}`);
}
```

});

Comment: Can you post your `Scene` schema declaration?